# Reference Time, Coordinating Conjunctions and Past Simple/Perfect Tense

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

This is an exercise from Face2Face English course with the solution provided in the workbook, but with no reasoning.

In the exercise below I would like to know (actually confirm mine) the Reference Time, and if there is *any level* of relationship between coordinating conjunctions and the sentence tense. For example, if, under some circumstances, the tense in the sentence before and after "and/but" is the same when there are no other clues such as time expressions.

> I finally *finished* tidying about 3 a.m. and a few minutes later I
>   ***was/had been*** fast asleep. I *woke up* suddenly at 8 a.m.  I ***arranged/had arranged*** to meet my parents at the airport at 8.30 a.m. but I ***didn't set/hadn't set*** the alarm!

To be specific, do you put both *arrange* and *set* in the same tense, or one of them in the past perfect and the other in the past simple (the course provides the answers but I **want to know why**, and know other speakers' opinions (esp. natives) other than the authors - sometimes there is more room for differences and I want to to know that?

-Usually, the arrangement is done before setting the alarm, but do you treat them as indefinite events with **no order** before the reference time? what is the reference time in the text *(this one is not given, but I can think of one*)?

**Note:** I could have written the exercise with just the answers and asked for the reasoning only, but I think it is better not to influence your answers by the author's. I could be wrong, but what I really want is to understand why.

Comment: Just want to check myself. (I've just read up to the quoted passage.) Are the answers: *was*, *had arranged*, and *didn't set*? --Just saw that *suddenly at 8 a.m.*

Comment: This is tricky. After I saw that *suddenly at 8 a.m.* I think *had been* is better than *was*, though *was* doesn't sound wrong to me. Waiting for the answers patiently... :)

Comment: You're definitely welcome. *Was* is right, but *arranged* and *set* (are different to the author's) - You did as I did the first time! We're much alike @DamkerngT. If you still want the answers before I get others posts I can send them off by email for example. I can still post them here if you want to.

Comment: I never thought of that, then let me try to invite you cause I've never tried it before. If I could not I would let you know. To the chat room,...

Comment: We already have a public chat room for ELL: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7227/english-language-learners. If you don't mind talking in public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I finished* ... *I was fast asleep* ... *I woke up at 8 a.m.* are ordinary narrative past forms in which RT moves forward with succeeding events.

When you hit *8 a.m.*, however, you find you must allude to  events which occurred before RT, your  arrangement with your parents and your failure to set the alarm. These two prior events—or this prior event and prior non-event!—give rise to the distressing state in which you found yourself at RT, 8 a.m.  Consequently you should employ the past perfect:

> I **had arranged** to meet my parents at the airport at 8:30 a.m. but I **hadn't** set the alarm!

This does not express any particular chronological sequence in the prior events because it does not 'express' the prior events *per se*: it alludes to the prior events as causes of your **current** (i.e. at RT = 8 a.m.) state of having to scramble to make your appointment.

Comment: **Just Beautiful!** You've already answered most of the issues if not all, but let me read your answer again and think of some [maybe] more questions for you because I think I could learn more out of the scenario than it was supposed to do.

Comment: I'm sorry for the typo the pick up time at the airport is at **8.30 a.m.** not 8 a.m, and I believe the moving RT was at when he woke up at 8 a.m. cause that is the last event he did before he talks about the arrangement.

Comment: "[he] alludes to the prior events as causes of your current (i.e. at RT = 8 **.30** a.m.) state of having missed your appointment." = the author was not in "narrative mode" of listing the events in the "story" but switched to "reasoning mode! if you wish" explaining the current state at RT by mentioning the causative events before RT.

Comment: If sleeping late which was narrated in the story was one of the causes of the current distressing state, can I still refer to it using the past perfect tense? i.e "I had fast slept late"? or it is a choice because it's already mentioned in the story in clear order?

Comment: @learner 1) I've corrected the time references and the nature of the current state. 2) You're still in 'narrative' mode, "located" at 8 am; you're just performing what I call in the Canonical Post a "cutaway perfect" to introduce, by the *reader's* inference, your current state. 3) Yes, "I had slept late" is fine - because at 8 am you are no longer asleep! :)

Comment: Thanks @StoneyB I have not seen your comment until now, I was tied up with writing and reading my other comments and questions. I think you've already answered my question about moving the furniture by answering the one about sleeping. You've been of great help to me; I really appreciate your quality answers.